# previewing a worklight app in Mobile Browser Simulator opens index.html but not View.html(created by WAF editor) in Worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Just followed the tutorial in the following link and created a worklight weather app but while previewing it on Mobile browser simulator it loads index.html. But created views from data objects using Workligt Application Framework editor.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/building_a_worklight_mobile_application_without_code_in_worklight_v6_1?lang=en

Can anyone please help me, how to set initial view view.html file.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Mobile Browser Simulator, as the application running on a real device always loads the index.html file. The Worklight Application Framework runtime code dynamically loads the views defined in the view.html file.

To select the initial view to be shown by the Worklight Application Framework runtime:

1) Open the application's common/application.json file using the Worklight Application
     Framework editor
   2) Go to the Views tab
   3) Right click on the view you want shown initially and click on "Set as initial view".

The selected initial view when working in the editor will have it's title bar's background color set to black. Save the application.json file and refresh the application in the Mobile Browser Simulator (if it's still open) by clicking the "Go" button.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser...but the same tutorial is working fine while running on windows machine...when I check the console(Mac-Chrome browser), I am getting "Unreferenced error: require is not defined." error...may be which is causing the application to load view.html file...can you please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, as of now worklight application framework editor works only with Dojo mobile toolkit.